# Convert to a Class Date but Add to a Data Frame Later On in R

Tags: r

Im trying to add a column to the existing data frame with dates (2010-01-03, 2010-01-02, .. ), but so it says which day of the week the date is (Sunday, Monday..). I had issues converting "to class 'Date'" and making the column like a data frame instead of just characters.

[I got my dataframe from here (2009-01-03 to 2010-01-02)](https://www.quandl.com/data/BCHAIN/AVBLS-Bitcoin-Average-Block-Size)

```
chart_2009 <- read.csv('BCHAIN-AVBLS (3).csv')
chart_2009_days = data.frame(date=c(chart_2009[1]))
chart_2009_days["2009 Days of the Week"] <- NA
chart_2009_days[2] <- weekdays(as.Date(chart_2009[1]))
```

Comment: So, your question is about how to convert to class date not how to get the week days - you should edit your title to reflect that. When you say "I had issues...", can you describe them? Were there error messages? Perhaps a warning message? What was the result? How do you know it went wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry you are right. Error in as.Date.default(chart_2009[1]) : do not know how to convert 'chart_2009[1]' to class “Date”

Comment: given that you know the functions `as.Date()` and `weekdays()`, it seems your issue is with the structure of your `chart_2009_days` object. Why have you created this object, can you do `chart_2009$days <- weekdays(as.Date(chart_2009[, 1]))`?

Comment: Thank you so much, chart_2009$days <- weekdays(as.Date(chart_2009[, 1])) worked

Comment: Also, it's often better to explicitly reference the columns you're using by name, rather than number, so something like `chart_2009$days <- weekdays(as.Date(chart_2009[, "date_column"]))` would be better

Comment: And finally, rather than link to an online data set in your question, you should provide a small reproducible example that others can use directly (as I did in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a column to a `data.frame` is as simple as

```
## create a dummy data.frame
df <- data.frame(date = c("2010-01-03", "2010-01-02"))
df
#         date
# 1 2010-01-03
# 2 2010-01-02

## add a new column
df$newColumn <- c("new", "column")
df
#         date newColumn
# 1 2010-01-03       new
# 2 2010-01-02    column
```

So there's no need for you to create a new object `chart_2009_days`, you can just append the column directly

```
chart_2009$days <- weekdays(as.Date(chart_2009[, 1]))
```

Noting that it's often better to reference the columns by name, rather than number, so it would be better to do

```
## I haven't seen your actual data so I'm just guessing the column name here
chart_2009$days <- weekdays(as.Date(chart_2009[, "date_column"]))
```